# How to synchronize Boss Looper pedal (RC-5) tempo with external drum machine (Korg Volca)?

Tags: tempo, looping, looper-pedals, korg, drum-machine

As a test case, I am trying to synchronize the tempo of the RC-5 Looper pedal to a Korg Volca drum machine. I tried two different ways with a TRS cable:

1. **Korg Volca `SYNC` `out` --> RC-5 `MIDI` `in`** No tempo change is noticeable on the RC-5. RC-5 `SYNC CLOCK` is set to `MIDI` and  `CLOCK OUT` is set to `OFF`
2. **RC-5 `MIDI` `out` --> Korg Volca `SYNC` `in`** Tempo on the Korg Volca is extremely fast, but also weirdly not synchronized, like a 3.5x multiplier. RC-5 `SYNC CLOCK` is set to `AUTO` and  `CLOCK OUT` is set to `ON`

Is this a specific incompatibility between these devices? Are there settings that I'm missing? I read the manual and have watched every tutorial I could find.

Comment: The Sync In / Out connections on Volca boxes are not MIDI, they are analog sync pulses, just plain voltage pulses. It just happens that the RC-5 uses the small TRS MIDI connectors, which are physically similar. If you send MIDI from RC-5 to Volca's Sync In, the Volca will see the signal from the MIDI messages as voltage pulses and it will react to that in some way. Try connecting the RC-5's MIDI output to the Volca's MIDI Input. You'll need a TRS - DIN MIDI cable for that.